# infinite scroll with angular - load x amount of data on each user scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to implement infinite scroll in my app but i'm finding difficulties. currently my json file has 30 records in it and when the page loads up, every data show up on the data. what i want to achieve is on the page load it show only show up 5 of the data ans when the user scrolls to the buttom the infinite scroll takes over and loads another 5 of the data and keep on repeating.

HTML

```
<ion-content> 

         <div class="list card has-subheader" ng-repeat="item in feeds track by item.u_pic_id">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <img src="../usr_up_img/{{item.profile_pix}}">
    <h2><a class="mylinks" href="#/tab/source/{{item.profile_id}}">{{item.fname}}&nbsp;{{item.lname}}</a></h2>
    <p>November 05, 1955</p>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-body">
    <img class="full-image" src="../images/{{item.profile_pix}}">
    <p>
      This is a "Facebook" styled Card. The header is created from a Thumbnail List item,
      the content is from a card-body consisting of an image and paragraph text. The footer
      consists of tabs, icons aligned left, within the card-footer.
    </p>

    <p>
      <a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.love_total}} Loves</a>
      <a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.com_total}} Comments</a>
    </p>
  </div>

</div>

<ion-infinite-scroll
    on-infinite="loadmore()"
    distance="1%">
  </ion-infinite-scroll>


      </ion-content>
```

JS

```
.controller('feedsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
    $scope.feeds = [];
    $scope.loadmore=function() {
        var params = {};
        if($scope.feeds.length > 0) {
            params['after']=$scope.feeds[$scope.feeds.length - 1].profile_id;
            }
$http.get('http://localhost/myapp/app_ion/feeds.php').success(function(data){
       $scope.feeds=console.log(data) ;
       $scope.feeds=data;
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');

   });
   }
}])
```

any help on how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.controller('feedsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.loadMore = function() {
    $http.get('http://localhost/myapp/app_ion/feeds.php').success(function(items) {
      $scope.items.push(items);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
    });
  }; 
  $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
    $scope.loadMore();
  });

}])
```

This is a example http://codepen.io/elm/pen/Becqp
If you need more help [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/)